# Ocsigen/Eliom: How to remove unnecessary JavaScript?

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

I'm taking my first steps in web programming with the Ocsigen framework. I can build simple apps, but I've noticed that Ocsigen generates loads of unnecessary JavaScript code. Even the [Hello world example](http://ocsigen.org/tuto/4.2/manual/how-to-make-hello-world-in-ocsigen), which has no interactive components at all, generates and includes a 400 KB JavaScript file. Is there a way to tell it not to do that?

I first noticed this issue while testing a simple app that was using internal links; testing with JavaScript turned off worked fine, but with JavaScript turned back on, I noticed that each link actually had an associated piece of JavaScript that I didn't write and can't control. Obviously, this code is not needed if the site works just as well without it. I would really like to avoid that. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's produced if you use the `Eliom_registration.App` functor. You can use `Eliom_registration.Html5` if you don't use javascript, and it will generate a plain html page without any magic in it. On the flip side, it means that you can't use client values.

Comment: Ah, that was easy. Thanks a lot!